# css: my list is fall down to next line when i resize my browser width

Tags: css

I have this code

```
<div class="mymenu">
    <div class="menu">
        <a href="#">home</a>
        <a href="#">home</a>
        <a href="#">home</a>
        <a href="#">home</a>
        <a href="#">home</a>
        <a href="#">home</a>
        <a href="#">home</a>
        <a href="#">home</a>
        <a href="#">home</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this css code

```
.mymenu {
    widht:100%;
    background: url(../images/mbg.png);
    height:40px;
    border-bottom: #21b8ff solid 4px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.mymenu.menu {
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-right: 60px;
}

.mymenu.menu a{
    margin-top:3px;
    float:right;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: SC_DUBAI;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-right: #4c4c4c solid 1px;
    border-left: #818181 solid 1px;
}

.mymenu .menu a:hover{
    color:#636363;
    background: #21b8ff;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

but when i resize my browser my menu fall down, how i can keep every a tag in line and if i resize my browser the a tag will hide and not fall to the next line??

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS like following.

check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K7tmK/) also. its working.

```
.mymenu {
    widht:100%;
    background: url(../images/mbg.png);
    height:40px;
    border-bottom: #21b8ff solid 4px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.mymenu .menu {
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-right: 60px;
}

.mymenu .menu a{
    margin-top:3px;
    float:right;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: SC_DUBAI;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-right: #4c4c4c solid 1px;
    border-left: #818181 solid 1px;
    height:40px;
}

.mymenu .menu a:hover{
    color:#636363;
    background: #21b8ff;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Eg : http://jsfiddle.net/K7tmK/

Answer (score 0):

just add `white-space: nowrap;` to your `.mymenu` in css.

See the working -> **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vkasarora/Sc2ST/1/)**